# How to handle inflections with CanCanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I have `ContactUsController` and `ContactUs` model.
In `contact_us_controller.rb`

```rb
class ContactUsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: :create
  load_and_authorize_resource

  ...
end
```

In `inflections.rb`

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable 'ContactUs'
end
```

I am using *CanCanCan* to handle authorization.
In `ability.rb` I have

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    unless user.present?
      can :create, ContactUs # guest users can create contact us
    end

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, ContactUs # only admins can do CRUD 
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ContactU Did you mean?  ContactUs):

activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:282:in `const_get'
...
```

I don't know why CanCanCan checks `ContactU` instead of `ContactUs`! Despite having an inflection for 'ContactUs' as *uncountable*.

Comment: try to restart server

Comment: I did. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by editing `inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable 'contact_us'
end
```